# laravel many to many ralationship 01

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

**How can I get role_id laravel many to many relationships**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Add",
        "slug": "menu/store",
        "created_at": "2018-02-27 19:01:00",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-27 19:01:00",
        "pivot": {
            "role_id": 1,
            "menuitem_id": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Hello dear please help me to solve it Thank you

Comment: You can see that is array of objects. You need to fetch first object passing numerical key to variable. Let say it is `$user` variable, try with `$user[0]->pivot->role_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve a single object of main table, then use `pivot`:

```
foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->role_id;
}
```

You can get more information and other helpers on [Laravel Documentation - Many to Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)